# Converter valor float para String

Tags: java, android, conversão-de-tipo

Estou programando para android, e estou tentando exibir um valor float encontrado pela função `getX()` em um Toast, que só exibe valores String. Como faço essa conversão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pra converter um valor float pra string, pode utilizar o método [`String.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-float-):

```
String str = String.valueOf(<valor float a ser convertido>);
```

Comment: Valeu! Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: @Bandicoot_ que bom que resolveu. Apenas uma dica para suas proximas perguntas, pra adicionar o código com o problema, neste caso foi possivel resolver sem vê-lo, mas dependendo do problema que tiver futuramente, pode ser mais complicado, pra se resguardar, sempre forneça um trecho ;)

Answer (score 0):

Você [pode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7552675/2387977) usar a própria classe `Float` do Java:

```
String s = Float.toString(25.0f);
```